# Why i cant use this python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, i made this as my first application. But now, i want to use it, and when  i select an option, i does not work

```py
def empezar():
    print ("Desea hacer bhaskara, forma polinomica a canonica, forma canonica a polinomica?")
    print ("(0=bhaskara, 1=canonica1, 2=canonica2, 3= canonica a polinomica)")
    print ("Recordar, que 1 es igual a una x")
    empezar = (input("Eleccion: "))
    if empezar == 3:
        poaca()
    elif empezar == 2:
        canonica2()
    elif empezar == 1:
        canonica1() 
    elif empezar == 0:
        inputs()

#Correr codigo
empezar()
```

Every function is defined and when i send a number, the code just get closed. But it does not have any errors and i was running before.

Comment: Change `empezar = (input("Eleccion: "))` to `empezar = int(input("Eleccion: ")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed code:

```
def empezar():
    print ("Desea hacer bhaskara, forma polinomica a canonica, forma canonica a polinomica?")
    print ("(0=bhaskara, 1=canonica1, 2=canonica2, 3= canonica a polinomica)")
    print ("Recordar, que 1 es igual a una x")
    empezar = (int(input("Eleccion: ")))
    if empezar == 3:
        poaca()
    elif empezar == 2:
        canonica2()
    elif empezar == 1:
        canonica1() 
    elif empezar == 0:
        inputs()
#Correr codigo
empezar()
```

I simply cast the value input() to an integer value and it is working just fine for me.

**Note: don't forget to implement the functions you are calling after checking the input**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use different name for variable from the function name. 
Also, please check all your functions and make sure they have a return or print inside. 
You could include those functions in your post.

```
def empezar():
    print ("Desea hacer bhaskara, forma polinomica a canonica, forma canonica a polinomica?")
    print ("(0=bhaskara, 1=canonica1, 2=canonica2, 3= canonica a polinomica)")
    print ("Recordar, que 1 es igual a una x")
    empezar_input = (input("Eleccion: "))
    if empezar_input == 3:
        poaca()
    elif empezar_input == 2:
        canonica2()
    elif empezar_input == 1:
        canonica1() 
    elif empezar_input == 0:
        inputs()
#Correr codigo
empezar()
```